# Why is accessing a private variable of a class as efficient as accessing a variable of a struct?

Tags: c++, algorithm, struct

I implemented some algorithm where the main data structure is a tree. I use a class to represent a node and a class to represent a tree. Because the nodes get updated a lot, I call many setters and getters.

Because I have heard many times that function calls are expensive, I was thinking that maybe if I represented the nodes and the tree using structs, it would make my algorithm more efficient in practice.

Before doing so I decided to run a small experiment to see if this is actually the case.

I created a class that had one private variable, a setter and a getter. Also I created a struct that had one variable as well, without setters/getters since we can just update the variable by calling `struct.varName`. Here are the results:

[image]

The number of runs is just how many times we call the setter/getter. Here is the code of the experiment:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#define BILLION  1000000000LL

using namespace std;

class foo{
private:
    int a;
public:

    void set(int newA){
        a = newA;
    }
    int get(){
        return a;
    }
};

struct bar{
    int a;
};

timespec startT, endT;

void startTimer(){
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &startT);
}

double endTimer(){
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &endT);
    return endT.tv_sec * BILLION + endT.tv_nsec - (startT.tv_sec * BILLION + startT.tv_nsec);
}


int main() {

    int runs = 10000000;
    int startRun = 10000;
    int step = 10000;
    int iterations = 10;
    int res = 0;
    foo f;
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("stats.txt", ios_base::out);
    fout<<"alg\truns\ttime"<<endl;
    cout<<"First experiment progress: "<<endl;
    int cnt = 0;
    for(int run = startRun; run <= runs; run += step){
        double curTime = 0.0;
        for(int iter = 0; iter < iterations; iter++) {
            startTimer();
            for (int i = 1; i <= run; i++) {
                f.set(i);
                res += f.get();
            }
            curTime += endTimer()/iterations;
            cnt++;
            if(cnt%10 == 0)
                cout<<cnt/(((double)runs-startRun+1)/step*iterations)*100<<"%\r";
        }
        fout<<"class\t"<<run<<"\t"<<curTime/BILLION<<endl;
    }

    int res2 = 0;
    bar b;
    cout<<"Second experiment progress: "<<endl;
    cnt = 0;
    for(int run = startRun; run <= runs; run += step){
        double curTime = 0.0;
        for(int iter = 0; iter < iterations; iter++) {
            startTimer();
            for (int i = 1; i <= run; i++) {
                b.a = i;
                res2 += b.a;
            }
            curTime += endTimer()/iterations;
            cnt++;
            if(cnt%10 == 0)
                cout<<cnt/(((double)runs-startRun+1)/step*iterations)*100<<"%\r";
        }
        fout<<"struct\t"<<run<<"\t"<<curTime/BILLION<<endl;
    }

    fout.close();
    cout<<res<<endl;
    cout<<res2<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why I get this behaviour. I thought that function calls were more expensive?

EDIT: I rerun the same experiment without -O3

[image]

EDIT: OK this is very surprising, by declaring the class in a separate file called `foo.h`, implementing the getters/setters in `foo.cpp` and running with -O3, it seems that the class becomes even more inefficient.

[image]

Comment: Can you please post the command used to compile your code?

Comment: Compilers are smart. Chances are very good that your getters and setters are optimized away completely. Also, public/private accessors have no impact on run-time performance, they checked during compile-time only. There is no performance penalty incurred from accessing private class members vs public struct members.

Comment: Your setter and getter are probably inlined, so it's equivalent to accessing the class members directly. And, in C++, there's no (runtime) difference between classes and structs.

Comment: I used the Clion ide, from the Cmakelists file the only flags are -O3 -std=c++11

Comment: You can make the function calls more expensive by compiling with no optimization (for debugging). Still it's generally not a good idea with getters and setters when they do not enforce some invariant or serve as debugging aids.

Comment: Aside: Well done for actually _measuring_ and _profiling_ your changes. Its the second rule for any decent optimization pass. Unfortunately the first rule, which you missed, was profiling the original code to actually see if there was a problem in the first place! A good lesson learned either way.

Comment: Please replace the order of the experiments and make sure that you get the same results, in order to eliminate "external factors" such as cache state, etc.

Comment: @jsguy: Now that you have determined that your compiler doesn't *by default* inline separately compiled code, you can try **global optimization** (which you can think of as performed at link time).

Comment: Hi Cheers, I am not sure I understand global optimization, is it some flag in the compiler that I need to use?

Comment: @jsguy: Yes. Apparently with g++ (and therefore probably also clang) it's the flag `-flto`. See discussion about how to use it at (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html). For Visual C++ it's apparently the flag `/GL`, documented at (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zza0de8.aspx).

Comment: thanks this worked and I did not have to declare anything to be inline. I will definitely have to try this with my main algorithm implementation, as I declared all setters/getters in a header file and implemented all functions in a cpp file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I have heard many times that function calls are expensive.

Was this in 1970 by any chance?

Compilers are smart. Very smart. They produce the best program they can given your source code, and unless you're doing something very weird, these sorts of design changes are unlikely to make much (if any) performance difference.

Most notably here, a simple getter/setter can even be completely inlined in most cases (unless you're doing something weird), making your two programs effectively *the same* once compiled! You can see this result on your graph.

Meanwhile, the specific change of replacing `class` with `struct` has no effect on performance whatsoever - both keywords define a *class*.

> I don't understand why I get this behaviour. I thought that function calls were more expensive?

See, this is why we don't prematurely optimise. Write clear, easy-to-read code without tricks and let your compiler take care of the rest. That's its job, and it's generally very good at it.

Comment: Re "Compilers are smart. Very smart.", this is a myth that gets bandied about a lot. It's true that compilers have some built-in smarts that ordinary developers would never think of, e.g. folding of arithmetic expressions with insane bitlevel tricks. But in the main compilers are still just very, very dumb. Look at the code gcc generates. Even a novice assembly programmer can do better at first try.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Compilers *are* smart; they're just not magic. Part of the problem is that the C/C++ standards require some things the assembly programmer wouldn't worry about (or might imagine they don't, and then get bitten). Another part of the problem is that it's often hard for the compiler to be sure that an optimization is safe (and sloppy programming makes this worse). And most of the problem is that you want the compiler to run fast and use a reasonable amount of memory.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I've done this a couple of times, every time being totaly amazed by how clever gcc is. I have some experience with writing assembly and probably can be called a 'novice', but I can't beat gcc, so you are wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The answer here is almost certainly compiler optimization. First of all, defining your getters and setters in the class definition makes them [inline](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/inline-functions#inline-member-fns-more). Even if you didn't do that, though, I'd expect any modern compiler to optimize away the function calls if they're in the same file and the compiler knows the resultant object is the whole program.

Comment: This being the modern age, whole-program optimisation should be achieved using LTO, not forcing your entire implementation into one cpp file.

Comment: I run some experiment testing this and it seems that if I declare the class in a file and implement the setters/getters in a separate .cpp file, I get a very bad performance...